# Find $d(x) = \gcd(f(x), g(x))$ and write $d(x)$ as a polynomial combination of both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $f(x) = x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$ and $\,g(x) = x + 1$ be two polynomials in $\mathbb{Z_2[x]}$

Find $d(x) = \gcd(f(x), g(x))$ and write $d(x)$ as a polynomial combination of both $f(x)$ and $\:g(x)$.

My attempt:

Dividing $f(x)$ by $g(x)$ using the division algorithm, we get $f(x) = (x+1)(x^3+1)$, and we have $g(x) = x + 1$.

Thus $d(x) = x+1$ ($\gcd(f(x), g(x)$) and $d(x) = 1.g(x) + 0.f(x)$

Is my attempt correct? Thank you

Comment: Where do you have a doubt? What about $(x+1)^2=x^2+1$, because $2=0$?

Comment: In my attempt, I found that $x+1$ is the gcd. And are you saying that $x^2+1$ is also a gcd?

Comment: This is correct. The fact that $g$ divides $f$ automatically makes $g$ a gcd. This is because $g$ is already the "largest" among its divisors and the fact that it is a common divisor of $g$ and $f$ implies it is the largest common divisor to both $g$ and $f$.

Comment: JOJO, no, I am only saying that $x^3+1$ is not irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$. So $f$ is not yet given as a product of irreducible factors.